# Reattaching Named Ranges in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove all Named Ranges in my Excel Workbook, store them in an Collection and after deleting, reattach them to my Workbook.

My Code looks like this

```
Sub ResetNamedRanges()
    Dim rName As Excel.Name
    Dim cName As Excel.Name
    Dim rangedNames As Excel.names
    Dim collNames As New Collection

    Set rangedNames = ThisWorkbook.names

    For Each rName In rangedNames
        collNames.Add rName 
        rName.Delete
    Next

    For Each cName In collNames
        names.Add cName.Name, cName.RefersTo, cName.Visible, cName.MacroType, cName.ShortcutKey, cName.Category, cName.NameLocal, cName.RefersToLocal, cName.CategoryLocal, cName.RefersToR1C1, cName.RefersToR1C1Local
    Next
End Sub
```

But it isn't working. Quit sure i'm missing something.

Comment: Your looping variable for going through `rangedNames` is `rName` but instead you're referencing `item`?? Why??  Your looping variable for going through `collNames` is `cName` but instead you're referencing `names`?? Why??  Correct your looping variable references

Comment: @tigeravatar Sry Typo...

Comment: You save in collection (?) `nameArray` and restore from collection `collNames`, that connot be working.

Comment: And even if you store to and restore from the same collection, since you are storing a reference to the object you probably ends up with a collection full of `Nothing` after your delete. Maybe you should explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: THis still won't work. The `.Delete` method removes any reference to the Name object that you put in the collection. Your collection will be full of Names which are not `Nothing`, but which aren't callable (and the Locals window will verify that every property yields an *Object Required*

Comment: @VincentG what's odd is that the collection items return `False` when tested against `Is Nothing`, but you're right, they are no longer referenced to a valid object, and so this code can't work to restore them.

Comment: I'm trying to reattach the 'Named Ranges' of my Workbook. I've got an workbook full of broken 'Named Ranges' and reattaching should fix this.

Comment: @DavidZemens It was just a (wrong) guess from my part, and this actually corresponds more to a collection of invalid references as you have said that a collection of `Nothing`s.

Comment: What I don't get is that a broken Named Range has probably wrong references in its fields, and just coping those broken links won't make them unbroken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary` and capture the relevant properties as such.

Your Collection method fails for reasons outlined in comments above: The `.Delete` method removes any reference to the `Name` object that you put in the collection. Your collection will be full of broken references, and you can't restore names from broken/invalid object references.

Option Explicit

```
Sub foo()
Dim rName As Name
Dim dictNames As Object

Set dictNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each rName In Names
        'We're going to use a dict for the properties, also:
        dictNames.Add rName.Name, Nothing
        Set dictNames(rName.Name) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With dictNames(rName.Name)
            ' Not my favorite way to do this, but some properties undefined will raise an error
            ' you can work a better way to do this if you prefer
            On Error Resume Next
            .Add "RefersTo", rName.RefersTo
            .Add "Visible", rName.Visible
            .Add "MacroType", rName.MacroType
            .Add "ShortcutKey", rName.ShortcutKey
            .Add "Category", rName.Category
            .Add "NameLocal", rName.NameLocal
            .Add "RefersToLocal", rName.RefersToLocal
            .Add "CategoryLocal", rName.CategoryLocal
            .Add "RefersToR1C1", rName.RefersToR1C1
            .Add "RefersToR1C1Local", rName.RefersToR1C1Local
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        rName.Delete
    Next

Dim itm
For Each itm In dictNames
    Set rName = Names.Add(itm, dictNames(itm)("RefersTo"))
    On Error Resume Next
    'rName.RefersTo = itm("RefersTo")
    rName.Visible = itm("Visible")
    rName.MacroType = itm("MacroType")
    rName.ShortcutKey = itm("ShortCutKey")
    rName.Category = itm("Category")
    rName.NameLocal = itm("NameLocal")
    rName.RefersToLocal = itm("RefersToLocal")
    rName.CategoryLocal = itm("CategoryLocal")
    rName.RefersToR1C1 = itm("RefersToR1C1")
    rName.RefersToR1C1Local = itm("RefersToR1C1Local")
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it worked, though I am curious to know what do you meant by "broken" Named Ranges (and incidentally, I'm not sure why *this* approach would be able to "fix" them...). If it has worked, do consider to accept the answer :)